# Does CnosDB Consider using Profile-Guided Optimization?

Tags: cnosdb

Not actually a problem - just an idea of how to possibly improve the performance of CnosDB

According to my tests, Profile-Guided Optimization (PGO) usually helps a lot with database - see my tests [here](https://github.com/zamazan4ik/awesome-pgo/). I think can interesting to test this approach on CnosDB as well.